# Firebase 3.0 failed initializeApp

Tags: firebase, typeerror

Migrating to firebase 3.0 but it's failed to initialize.

```
     var firebase = require('firebase');

      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "key",
        authDomain: ".firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: ".firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: ".appspot.com",
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

    module.exports ={

        return : {
            auth : firebase.auth,
            database : firebase.database(),
            storage : firebase.storage()
        }
    }

node_modules\firebase\auth-node\auth.js:61
throw new Error('Invalid service account provided');
at \node_modules\firebase\auth-node\index.js:31:9
at \node_modules\firebase\app-node.js:11:272
```

installed firebase : 3.0.2,
node : 4.4.2
"express": "^4.13.4"

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the correct setup settings from the Web Setup tab with the relevant APIkeys.

Comment: settings are correct , directly coped from web setup firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the [DEFAULT] app and reinitialize.  I think the code is somthing like

```
firebase.app.delete().then(function(){

)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Check it here: [Firebase "throw new Error('Invalid service account provided');" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424594/firebase-throw-new-errorinvalid-service-account-provided-error-message).

You need to create a service account and add it to your firebase app configuration.

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
})
```